# Caret with rxDForest as custom model

Tags: model, caret, error-message

I'm trying to use the `train` function from the caret package to tune the parameters of the `rxDForest` from RevoScaleR package (I can't use the random forest because my dataset is too big), but I can't manage to make my code work with resampling:

```
library(caret)
library(doParallel)
library(pROC)

registerDoParallel(cores=4)

# ----------------
# Import data train

load(file = "data_model_rf.RData")

# ----------------
# tune rf

rxDForest <- list(type = "Classification", library = "RevoScaleR", loop =     NULL,
                  parameters = data.frame(parameter = c("mTry",     "maxDepth"), 
                                              class = rep("numeric", 2),
                                              label = c("mTry", "maxDepth")),
                  grid = function(x, y, len = NULL) {
                                  p =     floor(sqrt(ncol(x)))
                                  expand.grid(mTry =     c(p/2,p,p*2), 
                                              maxDepth = c(1,3,5))},
                  fit = function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last,     weights, classProbs, ...) {
                                 tmp <-     as.data.frame(x)
                                 tmp$Class <- y
             f <-     as.formula(paste0("Class", " ~ ", 
                 paste(colnames(tmp)[-c(ncol(data_model))],collapse = "+")))
             rxDForest(f,     tmp, maxDepth = param$maxDepth,
                                 mTry = param$mTry,...)},
          predict = function(modelFit, newdata, preProc     = NULL, submodels = NULL) {
                                rxPredict(modelFit, newdata)},
          prob = function(modelFit, newdata, preProc =     NULL, submodels = NULL) {
              out <-     rxPredict(modelFit, newdata, type="prob")
              colnames(out)     <-  modelFit$obsLevels
                                      out[,1:length(modelFit$obsLevels)]},
          sort = function(x) {x[order(x$mTry, x$maxDepth     ),]},
          varImp = function(object, numTrees = NULL,     ...) {   
                varImp <-     object$importance
             out <-     data.frame(varImp)
                 colnames(out) <- "Overall"
                 rownames(out) <- rownames(object$importance)
                                    out})

rfGrid <- expand.grid(mTry = c(14), maxDepth = c(5))
fitControl = trainControl( method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, classProbs =     TRUE, 
                           repeats = 3, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)


# ----------------
# tune rf

rfFit <- train( data_model[,1:(ncol(data_model)-1)],     data_model[,ncol(data_model)], 
               method = rxDForest, trControl = fitControl, tuneGrid =     rfGrid, 
               metric = "ROC", verbose = TRUE, nTree = 20,     importance=TRUE )
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in train.default(data_model[, 1:(ncol(data_model) - 1)], data_model[,  : 
final tuning parameters could not be determined
4: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
5: In train.default(data_model[, 1:(ncol(data_model) - 1)], data_model[,  :
missing values found in aggregated results
```

The code works if I switch to `method = "none"` in the `trainControl` function, so it's not a problem with the `fit` or `predict` functions.
Thanks for your help.

EDIT :

Documentation for the rxDForest :

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-MIQzwMSpnxSlZXNjIxektEWmc/edit?pli=1

rxDForest accept only a specific "rxFormula" which doesn't include class~. but works with my syntax.

I've tried the new grid matrix (included x = matrix(1, ncol = 9, nrow = 10) in the grid function) but it doesn't work. I'm using the tunegrid option so the grid function is not supposed to be used, isn't it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there public documentation on `rxDForest`? This would be hard to reproduce without the software or documentation.

Comment: Does `rxDForest` have a non-formula interface (e.g. `rxDForest(x, y)`)? If so, using it may be more efficient. Also, you can probably just use `Class ~ .` as the formula instead of writing out a potentially huge one with each term. I doubt that this is the cause of the error but one never knows.

Comment: I would test your `grid` function more. It is not guaranteed to produce whole numbers for `mTry` (try using `x = matrix(1, ncol = 9, nrow = 10)`). This may cause errors in the model fit.

Comment: What I would do is stick a `browser()` line in your `fit` function and step through the code to see where it fails.

Comment: Finally it seems problem the came from the fact that rxDForest is parallelized and that caret also try to parallelized the cross validation process. I've deleted the registerDoParallel(cores=4) and now it works (only rxDForest is ran in parallel). I still get the error message "In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
There were missing values in resampled performance measures." but in the end i get a result.